# replace specific characters in a string

Tags: go

I have the following path:

```
/api/accounts/{account_id}/buy/{id}
```

but I wanted to sanitize this url by removing the first "{" to ":", which would look like this:

```
/api/accounts/:account_id/buy/:id
```

My question, is there a possibility of doing this with regex?

with replace it would be easy, but I don't need to replace them all, I need to remove the last `}`, and replace the first with `:`

Comment: Yes, it's possible with regex.  Is there a specific problem you encountered when trying?

Comment: @Matthew I can't think of how to put together the regex, [{-}], I always wanted to remove the last }, and replace the first with:

Comment: You can use `{(.+?)}` which will allow you to match the inner content (`account_id` and `id`), however I wouldn't consider this sanitizing the URL, as it doesn't account for malicious content or edge-cases.